# Monaco Editor 'onChange' event?

Tags: monaco-editor

I've just started investigating Monaco to be used as the editor for our internal code playground.  And I'm unable to figure out how to create a handler for whenever the text in the editor window is changed, either by typing, pasting, or deleting.  For context, using the CodeMirror editor, I simply did:

```
editor.on('change', function(editor, change) {
    render();
});
```

Here is my JavaScript that creates the basic editor:

```
    require.config({ paths: { 'vs': '../node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs' }});
require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function() 
{
    window.editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('editor'),                 
    {
        value: [
            'var canvas = document.getElementById("playground");',
            'var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");',
            'ctx.fillStyle = "#FF00FF";',
            'ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);',
        ].join('\n'),
        language: 'javascript'
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 32):

I found [onDidChangeContent](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.ITextModel.html#onDidChangeContent) method the other day.

In your example you would attach the listener like this:

```
window.editor.getModel().onDidChangeContent((event) => {
  render();
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  I had finally found onDidChangeContentModel which worked.  onDidChangeContent itself didn't work in my case.

Comment: The difference is that one is a method of the editor and one of a model. Note in my example that the method is called on window.editor.model

Comment: This is outdated with the last version, now it works with `editor.getModel().onDidChangeContent`

Comment: @dv1729 solution didn't work for me directly, but changing it to `editor.getModels()[0].onDidChangeContent` did work

Answer (score 25):

To expand on Gil's answer, there are two different methods, `onDidChangeContent` and `onDidChangeModelContent`.

- `onDidChangeContent` is attached to a model, and **will only apply to that model**
- `onDidChangeModelContent` is attached to the editor and **will apply to all models**

The nice thing is that you can use different `onDidChangeContent` listeners on multiple models, switch them out with one another, and they'll all preserve their own onChange events. For example, you might have an editor with different models for HTML, CSS, and JS. If you wanted different `onChange` listeners for each of those, this is easily achievable. At the same time, you can have listeners using `onDidChangeModelContent` that will apply to all models.

To update his answer, as of the current release (0.15.6), the syntax `editor.model` doesn't work. You have to use `editor.getModel()`.

Comment: It is [`onDidChangeModelContent`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.icodeeditor.html#ondidchangemodelcontent), not `onDidChangeContentModel`

Comment: @MarkusWeninger I thought I was doing something wrong until I saw your comment. I have edited the answer and fixed the typo.

Comment: I'd like to point out it wasn't a typo. It was correct for the version from Jan 2019, but since Monaco hasn't had a 1.0 release, they can change the API at any time.

Answer (score 15):

After a lot of poking and experimenting, I did find something.  I haven't figured out the difference between creating an editor and creating an editor using a model (not that I've looked), but the following works for me:

```
var monEditor;
require.config({ paths: { 'vs': '../node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs' }});
require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function() 
{
    monEditor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('editor'),                 
    {
        value: [
            'var canvas = document.getElementById("playground");',
            'var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");',
            'ctx.fillStyle = "#FF00FF";',
            'ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);',
        ].join('\n'),
        language: 'javascript'
    });
    monEditor.onDidChangeModelContent(function (e) {
        render();
    });
});
```

Using just onDidChangeContent did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

So, anyone looking for a guide on Monaco-editor can refer to this official document.
[Monaco Editor API](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.editor.html)